# Secure AWS S3 upload from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm implementing an AWS S3 POST upload directly from browser.
Access to the bucket is secured by a policy and allows CORS only for POST .

The policy has to be requested from my server which generates a policy for each file. The policy is strictly bind to the specific file that should be uploaded by using information like key-name, content-type and size.

To increase security I'm thinking about using different buckets.
One for public uploads described above, and a second private bucket which is only accessible by my server. If a file is uploaded successfully, my server copies the uploaded file to the second private bucket.

Do you think the copy process is sense full/necessary or just overhead?

Comment: Do you have a specific concern in mind?

Comment: The files i have to store are sensitive data to my users, therefore i have to avoid unauthorized access.